# XtraGrid in DevExpress and class?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am trying to fill an XtraGrid of DevExpress with a BindingSource that contains `List<MyiTems>`. When compiling the grid it works for me as illustrated by the first image below.

Now he did want that when playing some line of Grid he spread 1 Table and to see their content as sample the image 2 (I Need), like I can make this?

- Table: http://www.sendspace.com/file/pwxjuy
- Grids: http://www.sendspace.com/file/kpo1lj

THIS A NEW

J. Steen , I need to play is a row of the grid, which I display an array in a table below as pictured one of the URL, I understand...

Table Url  [url]http://www.sendspace.com/file/pwxjuy[/url]   I need this table displayed below the row you press
Grids URL  [url]http://www.sendspace.com/file/kpo1lj[/url]
Code  [url]http://www.sendspace.com/file/s46ryp[/url]

alex

Comment: I tried to understand your question but the second paragraph is just too hard to decipher. Could you try again, please.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to add a reference to this list/table in your MyiTems

```
Class MyiTems
{
    //some values
    List<SomeClass> ChildElements;
}
```